# How to Improve the ADO Lookup Speed?

Tags: sql-server, select, indexing, lookup

I write a C++ application via Visual Studio 2008 + ADO(not ADO.net). Which will do the following tasks one by one:

1. Create a table in SQL Server database, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
     [S] bigint, 
     [L] bigint, 
     [T] tinyint,   
     [I1] int, 
     [I2] smallint, 
     [P] bigint, 
     [PP] bigint, 
     [NP] bigint, 
     [D] bit, 
     [U] bit
);
```

2. Insert 5,030,242 records via `BULK INSERT`
3. Create an index on the table:

```
CREATE Index [MyIndex] ON MyTable ([P]);
```

4. Start a function which will lookup for 65,000,000 times. Each lookup using the following query:

```
SELECT [S], [L] 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE [P] = ?
```

**Each time the query will either return nothing, or return one row. If getting one row with the [S] and [L], I will convert [S] to a file pointer and then read data from offset specified by [L].**

Step 4 takes a lot of time. So I try to profile it and find out the lookup query takes the most of the time. Each lookup will take about 0.01458 second.

I try to improve the performance by doing the following tasks:

1. Use parametered ADO query. See step 4
2. Select only the required columns. Originally I use "Select *" for step 4, now I use `Select [S], [L]` instead. This improves performance by about 1.5%.
3. Tried both clustered and non-clustered index for [P]. It seems that using non-clustered index will be a little better.

Are there any other spaces to improve the lookup performance?

**Note**: `[P]` is unique in the table.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't look up each at a time would be my suggestion.RBAR is almost always slow

Comment: Once you have S and L, what do you do with it? Looking up a value 65 million times is not a good design pattern.

Comment: you can set many option for spped up your lookup maybe the partitioning in sql server can help you. if you wants the best speed for load data you can use In-Memory OLTP technic. at the next level you can config hadoop. before do this solution check your hardware buttelneck like old storage (hdd) or network workload

Comment: could you try with a covering index (to avoid the bmk lookup)? `create unique nonclustered index [MyIndex] ON MyTable ([P]) include([S], [L]);`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, after getting [S] and [L], I do some tasks with them.

Comment: @lptr, Thank you very much. I will try your solution after current test completes. By the way, what is BMK lookup. I search on Google, but do not find any info. I guess it is the abbreviation of "Bookmark"?

Comment: yes, you are right, it is the RID (row identifier) lookup for heaps

Comment: It was a leading question: if you ca ndo those tasks in a set based fashion in the database it will be much faster

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, It seems a bit difficult. Each time the query will either return nothing, or return one row. If getting one row with the [S] and [L], I will convert [S] to a file pointer and then read data from offset specified by [L]. This seems cannot be completed via a set based way.

Comment: You're doing this 65 million times? There's nothing you can do in the database to speed that up.

Comment: Either bulk insert the 65M rows into a staging table for a set-based process or pass a batch with a list of `P` values as a parameter (delimited, XML, JSON). A table-valued parameter is a better option but that's not supported in ADO classic.

Comment: You could also do all the lookups in your app instead of SQL Server. That will likely be the fastest.

Comment: @DanGuzman, Thank you. I use SQL Server because I think saving the data in my own file and lookup in my own way will not faster than SQL Server, since database is well-designed for large volume data management.

Comment: @alancc, if you were to bulk load the 65M rows and perform a set-based query, SQL Server would just build a hash table for the 5M row table and then perform 65M hash lookups. You could do the same in your app without pushing the data to SQL Server. It is true SQL Server is appropriate for relational database DML but you have not mentioned a RDBMS persistence requirement in your [x-y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

You need to batch the work and perform one query that returns many rows, instead of many queries each returning only one row (and incurring a separate round-trip to the database).

The way to do it in SQL Server is to rewrite the query to use a table-valued parameter (TVP), and pass all the search criteria (denoted as `?` in your question) together in one go.

First we need to declare the type that the TVP will use:

```
CREATE TYPE MyTableSearch AS TABLE (
    P bigint NOT NULL
);
```

And then the new query will be pretty simple:

```
SELECT
    S,
    L
FROM
    @input I
    JOIN MyTable
        ON I.P = MyTable.P;
```

The main complication is on the client side, in how to bind the TVP to the query. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with ADO - for what its worth, this is how it would be done under ADO.NET and C#:

```
static IEnumerable<(long S, long L)> Find(
    SqlConnection conn,
    SqlTransaction tran,
    IEnumerable<long> input
) {

    const string sql = @"
        SELECT
            S,
            L
        FROM
            @input I
            JOIN MyTable
                ON I.P = MyTable.P
    ";

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn, tran)) {

        var record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("P", SqlDbType.BigInt));

        var param = new SqlParameter("input", SqlDbType.Structured) {
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
            TypeName = "MyTableSearch",
            Value = input.Select(
                p => {
                    record.SetValue(0, p);
                    return record;
                }
            )
        };

        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            while (reader.Read())
                yield return (reader.GetInt64(0), reader.GetInt64(1));

    }

}
```

Note that we reuse the same `SqlDataRecord` for all input rows, which minimizes allocations. This is documented behavior, and it works because ADO.NET streams TVPs.

---

> Note: [P] is unique in the table.

Then you should make the index on P unique too - for correctness and to avoid wasting space on the uniquifier.

Comment: ADO classic does not support TVPs or new types introduced since SQL Server 2000. That said, one could use this ADO.NET technique in managed C++.

Comment: What is the advatange of TVP over parametered SQL Query? It seems that TVP is just similar to the latter.

Comment: @alancc TVP is just one of the ways you can parametrize a query. As opposed to a scalar parameter, a table-valued parameter allows you to pass many values to the query in one database round-trip. Note how `Find` accepts `IEnumerable<long>`, but calls `ExecuteReader` only once.

Comment: @alancc One more thing... ODBC apparently [supports TVPs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-table-valued-parameters/table-valued-parameters-odbc), so you can use pure ODBC from non-managed C++ (instead of ADO) in this case.